# WikiGameKiller.java - a program for solving Wiki game instances

Tags: java, game, wikipedia

### Intro

I have [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/coderodde/WikiGameKiller.java). Basically, it is a command-line utility for searching automatically for shortest link paths in the Wikipedia article graph.

The game in question is sometimes called **the Wiki Game**. The idea is that a player chooses two random Wikipedia articles (call them source and target) and the player tries to get from the source article to the target article only via links. The winner is the player who has found the shortest path compared to other players. If there’s more than one such players, the one who found the solution path the fastest wins.

### Limitations

(The node expanders also considers Show - sections as the source of links. If you cannot find the link via Ctrl+F, try first pressing all the `Show` links and retry the Ctrl+F find facility.)

### Code

**`com.github.coderodde.wikipedia.game.killer.WikiGameKiller.java:`**

```
import com.github.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.delayed.AbstractNodeExpander;
import com.github.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.delayed.impl.ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinder;
import com.github.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.delayed.impl.ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinderBuilder;
import com.github.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.delayed.impl.ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinderSearchBuilder;
import com.github.coderodde.wikipedia.graph.expansion.BackwardWikipediaGraphNodeExpander;
import com.github.coderodde.wikipedia.graph.expansion.ForwardWikipediaGraphNodeExpander;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class WikiGameKiller {
    
    /**
     * Specifies the HTML file format.
     */
    private static final String HTML_TEMPLATE = 
            """
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>WikiGameKiller.java</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div>%s</div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Shortest path:</h3>
                        <table>
            %s            </table>
                    </div>
                <body>
            </html>
            """;
    
    /**
     * Custom {@link PrintStream} for dealing with UTF-8 text.
     */
    private static PrintStream OUT;
    
    /**
     * The Wikipedia URL format.
     */
    private static final String WIKIPEDIA_URL_FORMAT =
            "^((http:\\/\\/)|(https:\\/\\/))?..\\.wikipedia\\.org\\/wiki\\/.+$";
    
    /**
     * The Wikipedia URL regular expression pattern object.
     */
    private static final Pattern WIKIPEDIA_URL_FORMAT_PATTERN = 
            Pattern.compile(WIKIPEDIA_URL_FORMAT);
    
    static {
        try {
            OUT = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            System.out.printf("ERROR: %.\n", ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(2);
        }
    }
            
    /**
     * This class simply holds all the command line arguments.
     */
    private static final class CommandLineArguments {
        String source           = null;
        String target           = null;
        String outFileName      = null;
        int threads             = ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinder.DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_THREADS;
        int trials              = ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinder.DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_MASTER_TRIALS;
        int masterSleepDuration = ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinder.DEFAULT_MASTER_THREAD_SLEEP_DURATION_MILLIS;
        int slaveSleepDuration  = ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinder.DEFAULT_SLAVE_THREAD_SLEEP_DURATION_MILLIS;
        int expansionTimeout    = ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinder.DEFAULT_EXPANSION_JOIN_DURATION_MILLIS;
        int lockWaitDuration    = ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinder.DEFAULT_LOCK_WAIT_MILLIS;
        boolean printHelp       = false;
        boolean printStatistics = false;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            CommandLineArguments commandLineArguments = 
                    parseCommandLineArguments(args);
            
            if (commandLineArguments.printHelp) {
                printHelp();
                return;
            }
            
            String source = commandLineArguments.source;
            String target = commandLineArguments.target;
            
            checkWikipediaArticleFormat(source);
            checkWikipediaArticleFormat(target);
            
            String languageCodeSource = getLanguageCode(source);
            String languageCodeTarget = getLanguageCode(target);
            
            if (!languageCodeSource.equals(languageCodeTarget)) {
                throw new CommandLineException(
                        String.format(
                                "Language code mismatch: \"%s\" vs \"%s\".", 
                                languageCodeSource, 
                                languageCodeTarget));
            }
            
            // Get the article names:
            source = source.substring(source.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            target = target.substring(target.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            
            source = URLDecoder.decode(source, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            target = URLDecoder.decode(target, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            
            ForwardLinkExpander forwardLinkExpander = 
                    new ForwardLinkExpander(languageCodeSource);
            
            BackwardLinkExpander backwardLinkExpander = 
                    new BackwardLinkExpander(languageCodeTarget);
            
            validateTerminalNodes(forwardLinkExpander,
                                  backwardLinkExpander, 
                                  source,
                                  target);
            
            ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinder<String> finder = 
                    ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinderBuilder.<String>begin()
                    .withJoinDurationMillis(commandLineArguments.expansionTimeout)
                    .withLockWaitMillis(commandLineArguments.lockWaitDuration)
                    .withMasterThreadSleepDurationMillis(commandLineArguments.masterSleepDuration)
                    .withSlaveThreadSleepDurationMillis(commandLineArguments.slaveSleepDuration)
                    .withNumberOfMasterTrials(commandLineArguments.trials)
                    .withNumberOfRequestedThreads(commandLineArguments.threads)
                    .end();
            
            List<String> path = 
                    ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinderSearchBuilder
                            .<String>withPathFinder(finder)
                            .withSourceNode(source)
                            .withTargetNode(target)
                            .withForwardNodeExpander(forwardLinkExpander)
                            .withBackwardNodeExpander(backwardLinkExpander)
                            .search();
            
            if (commandLineArguments.printStatistics) {
                OUT.printf(
                        "[STATISTICS] Duration: %d milliseconds, " + 
                        "expanded nodes: %d nodes.\n",
                        finder.getDurationMillis(),
                        finder.getNumberOfExpandedNodes());
            }
            
            final List<LinkPathNode> linkPathNodeList = 
                    new ArrayList<>(path.size());
            
            for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
                String title = path.get(i);
                title = URLDecoder.decode(title, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                title = title.replace("_", " ");
                
                String url = wrapToUrl(title, languageCodeTarget);
                linkPathNodeList.add(new LinkPathNode(url, title));
            }
            
            final int maximumUrlLength = getMaximumUrlLength(linkPathNodeList);
            
            for (final LinkPathNode linkPathNode : linkPathNodeList) {
                OUT.println(
                        linkPathNode.toCommandLineRow(maximumUrlLength));
            }
            
            if (commandLineArguments.outFileName != null) {
                saveFile(commandLineArguments.outFileName,
                         linkPathNodeList,
                         commandLineArguments.printStatistics,
                         finder.getDuration(),
                         finder.getNumberOfExpandedNodes());
            }
            
        } catch (final CommandLineException ex) {
            OUT.printf("ERROR: %s\n", ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the argument array has space for the argument at index 
     * {@code index}. If not, an instance of {@link CommandLineException} is
     * thrown.
     * 
     * @param args  the argument array.
     * @param index the index of an argument.
     * 
     * @throws CommandLineException if {@code index} does not fit in the input
     *                              argument array.
     */
    private static void checkValueFitsInCommandLine(String[] args, int index) {
        if (index >= args.length) {
            throw new CommandLineException(
                    String.format(
                            "The argument \"%s\" has no value.", 
                            args[index]));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the input URL {@code url} is a valid Wikipedia URL.
     * 
     * @param url the URL to check.
     * 
     * @throws an instance of {@link CommandLineException} if the input URL is 
     *         not a valid Wikipedia URL.
     */
    static void checkWikipediaArticleFormat(final String url) {
        Matcher matcher = WIKIPEDIA_URL_FORMAT_PATTERN.matcher(url);
        
        if (!matcher.find()) {
            throw new CommandLineException(
                    String.format(
                            "URL \"%s\" is not a valid Wikipedia URL.",
                            url));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Computes a map mapping each command line argument to its appearance 
     * index.
     * 
     * @param args the argument array.
     * 
     * @return a map mapping each command line argument to its appearnce index.
     */
    private static Map<String, Integer> computeArgumentMap(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(args.length);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            map.put(args[i], i);
        }
        
        return map;
    }
    
    /**
     * Attemtps to read an integer value of the {@code index}th argument.
     * 
     * @param args  the argument array.
     * @param index the argument array index.
     * 
     * @return the integer value of the {@code index}th argument.
     * 
     * @throws an instance of {@link CommandLineException} if either the index
     *         is outside of the argument array, or the {@code index}th argument
     *         is not an integer.
     */
    private static int getArgumentIntValue(final String[] args,
                                           final int index) {
        
        checkValueFitsInCommandLine(args, index);
        
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(args[index]);
        } catch (final NumberFormatException ex) {
            throw new CommandLineException(
                    String.format(
                            "\"%s\" is not an integer.",
                            args[index + 1]));
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Attempts to read a string value of the {@code index}th argument.
     * 
     * @param args  the argument array.
     * @param index the argument array index.
     * 
     * @return the string value of the {@code index}th argument.
     * 
     * @throws an instance of {@link CommandLineException} if the index is 
     *         outside of the argument array.
     */
    private static String getArgumentStringValue(String[] args, int index) {
        checkValueFitsInCommandLine(args, index);
        return args[index];
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the ISO language code used in the input URL {@code url}.
     * 
     * @param url the URL to extract the country code from.
     * 
     * @return the language code.
     * 
     * @throws an instance of {@link CommandLineException} if the resulting 
     *         language code does not conform to ISO.
     */
    private static String getLanguageCode(String url) {
        final String secureProtocol = "https://";
        final String insecureProtocol = "http://";
        
        if (url.startsWith(secureProtocol)) {
            url = url.substring(secureProtocol.length());
        } else if (url.startsWith(insecureProtocol)) {
            url = url.substring(insecureProtocol.length());
        }
        
        final String languageCode = url.substring(0, 2);
        
        if (!Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOLanguages()).contains(languageCode)) {
            throw new CommandLineException(
                    String.format(
                            "Unknown language code: %s",
                            languageCode));
        }
        
        return languageCode;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the maximum URL length extracted from {@code linkPathNodeList}.
     * 
     * @param linkPathNodeList the list of {@link LinkPathNode} objects.
     * 
     * @return the maximum URL length in {@code linkPathNodeList}. 
     */
    private static int getMaximumUrlLength(
            final List<LinkPathNode> linkPathNodeList) {
        
        int maximumUrlLength = 1;
        
        for (final LinkPathNode linkPathNode : linkPathNodeList) {
            maximumUrlLength = Math.max(maximumUrlLength,
                                        linkPathNode.url.length());
        }
        
        return maximumUrlLength;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the current name of this .jar file. Used in the help message.
     * 
     * @return the current name of this .jar file.
     */
    private static String getPath() {
        return new java.io.File(WikiGameKiller.class.getProtectionDomain()
          .getCodeSource()
          .getLocation()
          .getPath())
          .getName();
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the HTML code for the link path table.
     * 
     * @param linkPathNodeList the list of link path nodes.
     * 
     * @return the HTML code for the link path table.
     */
    private static String getPathTableHtml(
            final List<LinkPathNode> linkPathNodeList) {
        
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        
        int lineNumber = 1;
        
        for (final LinkPathNode linkPathNode : linkPathNodeList) {
            stringBuilder.append(linkPathNode.toTableRowHtml(lineNumber++));
        }
        
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    
    /**
     * Parses the entire command line excluding the Java VM call 
     * ({@code java -jar FILE.jar}).
     * 
     * @param args the array of arguments.
     * 
     * @return the {@code CommandLineArguments} object describing the command 
     *         line invocation.
     * 
     * @throws CommandLineException if there are problems with the command line.
     */
    private static CommandLineArguments
         parseCommandLineArguments(String[] args) {
             
        Map<String, Integer> map = computeArgumentMap(args);
        
        if (map.containsKey("--help")) {
            if (map.size() > 1) {
                throw new CommandLineException(
                        "--help must be the only argument.");
            }
            
            CommandLineArguments commandLineSettings = new CommandLineArguments();
            commandLineSettings.printHelp = true;
            return commandLineSettings;
        }
        
        if (!map.containsKey("--source")) {
            throw new CommandLineException("--source option is missing.");
        }
        
        if (!map.containsKey("--target")) {
            throw new CommandLineException("--target option is missing.");
        }
        
        CommandLineArguments commandLineArguments = new CommandLineArguments();
        
        commandLineArguments.source = 
                getArgumentStringValue(args, map.get("--source") + 1);
        
        commandLineArguments.target = 
                getArgumentStringValue(args, map.get("--target") + 1);
        
        if (map.containsKey("--out")) {
            commandLineArguments.outFileName = 
                getArgumentStringValue(args, map.get("--out") + 1);
        }
        
        if (map.containsKey("--stats")) {
            commandLineArguments.printStatistics = true;
        }
        
        if (map.containsKey("--threads")) {
            int index = map.get("--threads");
            commandLineArguments.threads = getArgumentIntValue(args, index + 1);
        }
        
        if (map.containsKey("--master-trials")) {
            int index = map.get("--master-trials");
            commandLineArguments.trials = getArgumentIntValue(args, index + 1);
        }
        
        if (map.containsKey("--master-sleep-duration")) {
            int index = map.get("--master-sleep-duration");
            commandLineArguments.masterSleepDuration = 
                    getArgumentIntValue(args, index + 1);
        }
        
        if (map.containsKey("--slave-sleep-duration")) {
            int index = map.get("--slave-sleep-duration");
            commandLineArguments.slaveSleepDuration = 
                    getArgumentIntValue(args, index + 1);
        }
        
        if (map.containsKey("--expansion-timeout")) {
            int index = map.get("--expansion-timeout");
            commandLineArguments.expansionTimeout = 
                    getArgumentIntValue(args, index + 1);
        }
        
        if (map.containsKey("--lock-wait-timeout")) {
            int index = map.get("--lock-wait-timeout");
            commandLineArguments.lockWaitDuration = 
                    getArgumentIntValue(args, index + 1);
        }
        
        return commandLineArguments;
    }
         
    /**
     * Prints the help message.
     */
    private static void printHelp() {
        OUT.printf(
        """
        usage: %s
            --source SOURCE_ARTICLE_URL
            --target TARGET_ARTICLE_URL
           [--threads NUMBER_OF_THREADS]
           [--master-trials TRIALS]
           [--master-sleep-duration MASTER_SLEEP_MILLIS]
           [--slave-sleep-duration SLAVE_SLEEP_MILLIS]
           [--expansion-timeout EXPANSION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS]
           [--lock-wait-timeout LOCK_WAIT_MILLIS]
           [--help]
           [--stats]
           [--out OUTPUT_HTML_FILE_NAME]
        
            where:
                NUMBER_OF_THREADS        - the total number of threads.        Default is %d.
                TRIALS                   - the number of master thread trials. Default is %d.
                MASTER_SLEEP_MILLIS      - the number of milliseconds.         Default is %d.
                SLAVE_SLEEP_MILLIS       - the number of milliseconds.         Default is %d.
                EXPANSION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS - the number of milliseconds.         Default is %d.
                LOCK_WAIT_MILLIS         - the number of milliseconds.         Default is %d.
        
                --help  - Print this help message.
                --stats - Print the search statistics after the search.
        """,
        getPath(),
        ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinder.DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_THREADS,
        ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinder.DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_MASTER_TRIALS,
        ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinder.DEFAULT_MASTER_THREAD_SLEEP_DURATION_MILLIS,
        ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinder.DEFAULT_SLAVE_THREAD_SLEEP_DURATION_MILLIS,
        ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinder.DEFAULT_EXPANSION_JOIN_DURATION_MILLIS,
        ThreadPoolBidirectionalBFSPathFinder.DEFAULT_LOCK_WAIT_MILLIS
        );
    }
    
    /**
     * Attempts to save the results to an HTML file.
     * 
     * @param fileName              the name of the saved file.
     * @param linkPathNodeList      the link path node list.
     * @param showStats             if {@code true}, statistics will be saved.
     * @param duration              the duration of the search.
     * @param numberOfExpandedNodes the number of expanded nodes.
     * 
     * @throws CommandLineException if something goes wrong.
     */
    private static void saveFile(final String fileName,
                                 final List<LinkPathNode> linkPathNodeList,
                                 final boolean showStats,
                                 final long duration,
                                 final int numberOfExpandedNodes) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        
        if (file.exists()) {
            if (!file.delete()) {
                throw new CommandLineException(
                        String.format(
                                "Could not delete the file \"%s\".", 
                                fileName));
            }
        }
        
        String html;
        
        if (showStats) {
            html = String.format(
                    HTML_TEMPLATE,
                    String.format(
                            "Duration: %d milliseconds, expanded %d nodes.", 
                            duration, 
                            numberOfExpandedNodes),
                    getPathTableHtml(linkPathNodeList));
        } else {
            html = String.format(
                    HTML_TEMPLATE, 
                    "",
                    getPathTableHtml(linkPathNodeList));
        }
        
        try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =
                new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
            
            bufferedWriter.write(html);
            bufferedWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new CommandLineException(
                    "Could not create a buffered writer.");
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Strinps the protocol, host name and {@code wiki} path from each URL in
     * the {@code urlList}. For example, 
     * {@code https://en.wikipedia.org/en/Hiisi} becomes simply {@code Hiisi}.
     * 
     * @param urlList the list of URLs.
     * @return the list of stripped URLs.
     */
    private static List<String> stripHostAddress(final List<String> urlList) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(urlList.size());
        
        for (final String url : urlList) {
            result.add(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
    /**
     * Makes sure that the two terminal nodes are valid Wikipedia article nodes.
     * 
     * @param forwardExpander  the forward link expander.
     * @param backwardExpander the backward link expander.
     * @param source           the source node.
     * @param target           the target node.
     * 
     * @throws CommandLineException if could not validate both terminal nodes.
     */
    private static void validateTerminalNodes(
            final AbstractNodeExpander<String> forwardExpander,
            final AbstractNodeExpander<String> backwardExpander,
            String source, 
            String target) {
        
        if (!forwardExpander.isValidNode(source)) {
            throw new CommandLineException(
                    String.format(
                            "The source node \"%s\" is not a valid node.",
                            source));
        }
        
        if (!backwardExpander.isValidNode(target)) {
            throw new CommandLineException(
                    String.format(
                            "The target node \"%s\" is not a valid node.",
                            target));
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Wraps {@code articleTitle} and {@code languageCode} into a valid 
     * Wikipedia URL.
     * 
     * @param articleTitle the title of the article.
     * @param languageCode the language code of the article.
     * 
     * @return a full Wikipedia URL.
     */
    private static String wrapToUrl(final String articleTitle, 
                                    final String languageCode) {
        
        return String.format("https://%s.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s", 
                             languageCode, 
                             URLEncoder.encode(
                                     articleTitle, 
                                     Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
                .replace("+", "_");
    }
    
    public static final class CommandLineException extends RuntimeException {
        
        CommandLineException(final String exceptionMessage) {
            super(exceptionMessage);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * This class implements the forward link expander.
     */
    private static final class ForwardLinkExpander 
            extends AbstractNodeExpander<String> {

        private final ForwardWikipediaGraphNodeExpander expander;
        
        public ForwardLinkExpander(final String languageCode) {
            this.expander = new ForwardWikipediaGraphNodeExpander(languageCode);
        }
        
        /**
         * Generate all the links that this article links to.
         * 
         * @param article the source article of each link.
         * 
         * @return all the article titles that {@code article} links to.
         */
        @Override
        public List<String> generateSuccessors(final String article) {
            List<String> urlList = expander.generateSuccessors(article);
            return stripHostAddress(urlList);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValidNode(final String article) {
            return expander.isValidNode(article);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * This class implements the backward link expander. 
     */
    private static final class BackwardLinkExpander 
            extends AbstractNodeExpander<String> {

        private final BackwardWikipediaGraphNodeExpander expander;
        
        public BackwardLinkExpander(final String languageCode) {
            this.expander = 
                    new BackwardWikipediaGraphNodeExpander(languageCode);
        }
        
        /**
         * Generate all the links pointing to the article {@code article}.
         * 
         * @param article the target article of each link.
         * 
         * @return all the article titles linking to {@code article}.
         */
        @Override
        public List<String> generateSuccessors(final String article) {
            List<String> urlList = expander.generateSuccessors(article);
            return stripHostAddress(urlList);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValidNode(final String article) {
            return expander.isValidNode(article);
        }
    }
    
    private static final class LinkPathNode {
        private final String url;
        private final String title;
        
        LinkPathNode(final String url, final String title) {
            this.url = url;
            this.title = title;
        }
        
        String toTableRowHtml(final int lineNumber) {
            return new StringBuilder().append("                ") // Align.
                                      .append("<tr><td>")
                                      .append(lineNumber)
                                      .append(".</td><td><a href=\"")
                                      .append(url)
                                      .append("\">")
                                      .append(url)
                                      .append("</a></td><td>")
                                      .append(title)
                                      .append("</td></tr>\n")   
                                      .toString();
        }
        
        String toCommandLineRow(int urlLength) {
            return String.format(
                    "%-" + urlLength + "s  [%s]", 
                    url.replace("+", "_"),
                    title);
        }
    }
}
```

### Example output

```
java -jar WikiGameKiller.java-1.0.0.jar --source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugatti --target https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language) --threads 128 --stats --out ..\index.html --expansion-timeout 4000

[STATISTICS] Duration: 4383 milliseconds, expanded nodes: 931 nodes.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugatti
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2024_Formula_One_World_Championship
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29
```

### Critique request

As always, I am eager to receive any constructive commentary regarding my work. Is naming in order? Overall program structure?